# Temporary memory leak in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage

I have a big picture that consists of small pictures of 50 * 50 pixels. Number of small pictures n * m. You need to make a small copy of 50 * 50 -> 2 * 2 for each picture. I launch the code - on the simulator it is visible that at this stage it is 1.3-1.4 GB of RAM, so on real devices the crash goes on. N = 200 m = 180

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions (CGSize (width: n * 2, height: m * 2), false, 0.0) var cellImage: UIImage? For y in 0 ..



 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: n*2, height: m*2), false, 0.0)
 var cellImage : UIImage?
 for y in 0..<n {
    for x in 0..<m {
                cellImage = вызов функции для получения картинки 50*50...
                cellImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: y*2, y: x*2, width: 2, height: 2))
                cellImage = nil
     }
 }

        // End
        miniViewImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: this site uses english as a language

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

revise as follows:

```
   for x in 0..<m {
      autoreleasepool {
                cellImage = вызов функции для получения картинки 50*50...
                cellImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: y*2, y: x*2, width: 2, height: 2))
                cellImage = nil
      }
   }
```

This will release memory each step of the iteration.